# Gridview sorting with bound fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10" DataKeyNames="CategoryID" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        GridLines="Vertical" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" onsorted="GridView1_Sorted" 
        onsorting="GridView1_Sorting">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="categoryid" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="CategoryID" />        
        </Columns>        
    </asp:GridView>
```

Sorting does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you handle your onsorting event?

Comment: There is nothing in that event handler

Comment: How you are binding your grid using `SQLDataSource` or `DataSet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sorting event handler, you can change the sort property on Data table.

```
  dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
  gv.DataSource = dt;
  gv.DataBind();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx